# Drivers in C++ produces bigger assembly

Tags: c, assembly, c++

I'm trying to figure out whether C++ is a suitable language for use in device drivers, like peripherals on Cortex-M3/M4.

I started writing some drivers for GPIO and I noticed that it produces bigger assembly. I'm doing some experiments on https://godbolt.org/.

A piece of code that executes an action on a GPIO peripheral and set a specific pin as high would look like this:

```
void gpio_set_high(int x)
{
    (base + x) |= 1;
}
```

In C++ that would be done like this:

```
class GPIO
{
public:
    GPIO(int x)
    {
        pin = x;
    }

    void setHigh()
    {
        (base + pin) |= 1;
    }

private:
    int pin;
};
```

First the question is, why does the class produces bigger assembly?

Comment: Are you really comparing a function with a class with a function and bells/whistles?

Comment: It doesn't. Full stop. If it does, you do not have optimizations turned on.

Comment: @CodyGray some compilers (IAR is famous for that) purposely have bad optimization since they need to certify that they work correctly for safety purpose; optimizers of course make proving that more difficult. A gcc with -O2 or -Os should generate the same code however

Comment: It would be more useful if you edited the question with actual generated code and the compiler option you used

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio Yes, indeed it does! You're right! Thank you for your comment!

Comment: by the way, your code isn't correct and wouldn't even compile like this: I'll assume `base` is  a pointer, so that `base + pin` is another pointer a bit further down. Or `base` is (incorrectly!) an integer holding the address (C++ will hit you with a shovel and not compile); you need to dereference like `*(base + pin)`

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes that's for presentation purposes only! I'm assuming people who will answer are more experienced than me and would understand the example code

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio Optimization has nothing to do with safety. You can just test and certify the code with optimizations turned on. If you're using a compiler with a bad optimizer, you're only doing yourself a disservice, especially considering that GCC is free and open-source, allowing everything it does to be fully studied if the requirements are truly that arduous (most are not). There is an awful lot of hand-waving about compiler optimizations. I would have thought that died out back in the 90s. Disappointing to see theses myths still propagated on a site like this one.

Comment: @CodyGray "Optimization has nothing to do with safety" We may wish that was true and maybe it was for gcc somewhere between year 2005-2015. But in latter years the number of gcc updates have escalated and people are finding hundreds of compiler bugs and non-conforming behavior every year. A lot of them are related to code optimization (just [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70380510/non-conforming-optimizations-of-volatile-in-gcc-11-1)) and therefore the gcc compiler is kind of a ticking bomb when optimizations are on, though less explosive with them off.

Comment: @CodyGray not so easy. For functional safety some entity require *(semi)formal proof* of correctness of generated code. Even a keyhole optimizer becomes difficult to handle in that situation

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio Functional safety may also insist on "verified" compilers... which I don't think neither IAR nor gcc lives up to. Possibly Wind River or something exotic like that. Some requirements of the functional safety standards are just not practically achievable.

Comment: IIRC for some compilers IAR is verified at least for MISRA requirements. Of course MISRA is a *quite* reduced subset of C (as in *you can't use pointer or dynamic allocation*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First the question is, why does the class produces bigger assembly?

You just introduced a class! That means you get longer method names (keyword: *name mangling*), if you're building with such embedded (e.g. a debug build, or you forgot to set default visibility to hidden, or…);  you very much added another function (the constructor) that your C implementation did not have, and you're adding a storage location for the `pin` variable, which your C code simply did not have, but which needs instructions to be put somewhere on object initialization.

So, these two implementations are very different; there's no reason to assume they're the same code size!

Matter of fact, however, in real-world usage, both compile down to exactly the same code (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/asPWKTb1c):

```
int test_class() {
    GPIO gpio(12);
    gpio.setHigh();
}
int test_plain_C() {
    gpio_set_high(12);
}
```

Slightly optimized for speed `-O2`:

```vhdl
test_class():
        adrp    x0, base
        ldr     x1, [x0, #:lo12:base]
        ldr     w0, [x1, 48]
        orr     w0, w0, 1
        str     w0, [x1, 48]
test_plain_C():
        adrp    x0, base
        ldr     x1, [x0, #:lo12:base]
        ldr     w0, [x1, 48]
        orr     w0, w0, 1
        str     w0, [x1, 48]
```

Optimized for size `-Os` (note how this - although it actually only *increases* the size – does not inline the C function, but does inline all C++! That's actually a feat of C++, it makes it easier for compilers to reason about things that are purely local state):

```vhdl
gpio_set_high(int):
        adrp    x1, base
        sxtw    x0, w0
        ldr     x2, [x1, #:lo12:base]
        ldr     w1, [x2, x0, lsl 2]
        orr     w1, w1, 1
        str     w1, [x2, x0, lsl 2]
        ret
test_class():
        adrp    x0, base
        ldr     x1, [x0, #:lo12:base]
        ldr     w0, [x1, 48]
        orr     w0, w0, 1
        str     w0, [x1, 48]
test_plain_C():
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
        mov     w0, 12
        mov     x29, sp
        bl      gpio_set_high(int)
```

All in all, *acshually*, your C code produces less compact binary code, as soon as you use your compiler in any setting that you would on a microcontroller. So, I'm afraid your initial assumption is a bit of an academic nature: *If* you cared about assembly size, *and* are using C++, *and* explicitly forget to use standard compiler flags.

Comment: Nice test! Also modern C++ has all the constexpr machinery and explicit assumptions on access ordering, that would probably help in many situations

Comment: ah, you can't `constexpr` something that access a `volatile` memory location for the purpose of changing state :) But in general, yes, C++ tells your compiler a lot more about the things you're *not* doing than C allows you to do, and hence, compilers can optimize things better.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the quality of the optimizer (auto inlining especially) and the fact that in the first case you can easily fit x in a register in the calling sequence while in a class you need a memory fetch;

Better ask in some Cortex group or to the compiler manufacturer since it's really processor/ABI dependant.

Also, I found that those universal driver approaches usually make bigger code than dedicated driver functions for some peripheral (at least on MSP430, I don't have ARM experience but generality vs performance is a typical tradeoff). This is even more evident with complex peripherals like timers: often even if you use a timer only for interval ticking often the library pulls in some code for using it as a counter or whatever.

Comment: *"in the first case you can easily fit x in a register in the calling sequence while in a class you need a memory fetch"* Huh? The code is identical in the C and C++ versions. Why would you need a memory fetch in one but not the other?

Comment: *Theorically* the pin is a member and you could say instance->setHigh(); however any useful compiler seeing instance.setHigh() should optimize the fetch away (if the function is inline)